# NULL value to SQL database if the user input is empty

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I get user input date from a box and save that value in a SQL sever cell called `Originated`. If a user enters a correct date, this code works fine and update the cell `Originated` with a value. However, if the user doesn't enters a value in the date box, my SQL query will automatically assign `1900-01-01`. I would like it to assign the value `NULL` if no input received. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<?php   
    $connInfo = array(
        'Database' => 'databasename',
        'UID' => 'user',
        'PWD' => 'pasword',
        'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true 
        );

    $connectString = sqlsrv_connect('sever.name.com', $connInfo) or die("Can't connect to the database");

    echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">Originated Date<input id=\"Originated\" type=\"date\" name=\"Originated\" \" >
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" /></form>";

    $Originated = $_POST['Originated'];     
    echo "<br>Originated date is:".$Originated;

        //if the unser input value is empty, this going to assin 1900-01-01 to the table. I want it to assign NULL
    $query_update = "UPDATE ElectronicShop SET Originated='$Originated' WHERE WorkOrder=5";
    $data = sqlsrv_query($connectString, $query_update) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL), true));       


    if($data)
    {
        echo "<br><h3>Table was updated Successfully</h3>"; 
        echo "<br><form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">Click here to go back: <input type=\"submit\" name=\"refresh\" value=\"Refresh\"/></form><br><br>";
    }               
    else 
    {
        echo "<br><h3>Unable to update the database</h3>";  
        echo "<br><form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">Click here to go back: <input type=\"submit\" name=\"refresh\" value=\"Refresh\"/></form><br><br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Make it so that your column has a default value then.

Comment: Try **SET Originated=NULLIF('$Originated','')**

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks. `SET Originated=NULLIF('$Originated','')` worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: My originated date is `'; --` but when I enter it all entries on your site get reset back to `1900-01-01`. Maybe you should protect yourself against SQL injection or verify the input before passing it into generated SQL.